# If Database connection failed try to reconnect

Tags: perl

I am newbie to perl , My scenario is m having an array of host ,
In a loop i am creating DNS and connection to database .
  But if any host is not responding or down , then that loop is getting break 
and remaining host not able to connect , My question is how can i skip that 
means if any host is not able to connect then i want to skip that host and want to connect with other one...
Hi all ,
   I am newbie to perl , My scenario is m having an array of host .

In a loop i am creating DNS and connection to database .
  But if any host is not responding or down , then that loop is getting break 
and remaining host not able to connect .

My question is how can i skip that 
means if any host is not able to connect then i want to skip that host and want to connect with other one...Or try to reconnect that host again ...

snippet of code is given bellow

```
@arr_ =('host1','host2');
foreach $host (@arr_){
   @Mydsn =("dbi:mysql:$MYSQL_DATABASE:$host:$MYSQL_PORT","$MYSQL_USER","$MYSQL_PWD");

my $my_connection =  DBI->connect(@Mydsn, { RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 1 } )  or die("Fail to connect Database  connection");
 ### Here how can i skip if mysql is not able to connect with breaking execution of script

}
```

Please help me out !
Thanks in advance
   Please help me out !
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide code and a specific question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

`die` immediately stops the script. Use `next` instead. Adapting your code above:

```
my @arr = ('host1','host2');
foreach my $host (@arr){
    my @mydsn = ("dbi:mysql:$MYSQL_DATABASE:$host:$MYSQL_PORT","$MYSQL_USER","$MYSQL_PWD");
    my $my_con = DBI->connect(@Mydsn, { RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 1 } );
    if ( ! $my_con ) {
        warn "failed to connect to $host";
        next;
    }
}
```

In this simple case, `next` is of course unnecessary.

Comment: @user356135: Please read the perl documentation, in particular [perlintro: looping constructs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Conditional-and-looping-constructs)

Comment: @user356135: It doesn't need the `next` because that's the last command in the loop, so it will go on the next element automatically without needing to be specifically told to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if the server is alive first, something similar to:

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
@arr_ =('host1','host2');
foreach $host (@arr_) {
    $sk = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $host, 
                                PeerPort => '5432', # if postgres
                                Proto    => 'tcp' );
    if ($sk) {
        my $my_connection =  DBI->connect(@Mydsn, { RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 1 } ) 
                 or die("Fail to connect Database  connection");
    } 
}
```